# Reliable Linux RAID Card

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

Can anyone recommend an appropriate RAID card for use under Linux (Ubuntu)? I have three Western Digital SATA drives, and would like to setup either RAID-1 or RAID-5. Software RAID has been very flakey and unreliable for me (e.g. it doesn't seem to mirror the boot partition).

Unfortunately, most RAID cards I've seen online don't mention any Linux driver support. Would most cards work in Linux, or do I have to look at a select few that explicitly support Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this card, [3ware 9650se](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816116076&cm_re=3ware-_-16-116-076-_-Product), on linux (and older build of slackware no less). This card had a full suite of management utilities for linux.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want.  I noticed the software-raid tag, do you really want software raid?  If so, why do you need a card?  Simply use [MDADM](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=408461)...

If you want TRUE hardware raid, the OS normally doesn't matter much since it appears to the OS as a single drive anyway.  I say "much", because performance may take a hit if you don't have the exact drivers (Example:  The IBM ServeRAID hardware controllers work great under RHEL or CentOS, but crappy under any Debian derivative, because they don't have the proper driver).

Comment: Thanks. I'm targeting Ubuntu, so it's good to know the distro matters. I would have thought the drivers would work on any distro that uses the same kernel.

Comment: They typically do.  But not all distros ship the same driver set...